# Is it possible to debug UWP (Win10) Xaml user control in Design Mode (Xaml Designer) on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml, xaml-designer

I run two instances of VS 2015, the second one instance is attached to XDesProc.exe (Xaml Designer) of the first one VS 2015 instance and breakpoints in user control code behind file are inactive after opening xaml file in Xaml Designer on first instance of VS 2015 (I ran VS 2015 with admin privileges also).

Is it possible to debug **UWP** xaml controls in design mode at all (when xaml designer claims the control throws some exceptions and can't be instantiated)?

Answer (score 0):

- Disable the option "Enable Just my Code" in: VS->Tools->Options->Debugger.
- Confirm the debugger can access the symbols (.PDB files), look for messages in the Output Window
- When attaching, make sure you select .Net 4.6

Yes, you can enable "First Chance Exceptions", go to Debug->Windows->Exception Settings.

Comment: Attaching to what? XDescProc.Exe? Also, what does it mean "make sure you select .net 4.6"?

When I attach to XDescProc.exe symbols for my apps are never loaded